How to Save User Input to CSV in Python BeeWare Toga App?
I'm developing a simple app using Python, BeeWare, and Toga to collect daily data on my weight. The app should ask me for the date and my weight, then save this information to a CSV file. Currently, I have a basic window that asks for the inputs but doesn't do anything with them yet.
I'm looking for guidance on how to capture the input from the user and save it to a CSV file using classes in Toga. Below is the code I have so far:
    import toga

class WeightApp(toga.App):
    def startup(self):
        # Create a main window with a name and size
        self.main_window = toga.MainWindow(title=self.name)

        # Create a box container to hold the widgets
        box = toga.Box()

        # Create the first user input for the date
        self.date_input = toga.TextInput(placeholder='Enter date (YYYY-MM-DD)')
        self.date_input.style.padding = 50
        box.add(self.date_input)

        # Create the second user input for the weight
        self.weight_input = toga.TextInput(placeholder='Enter weight')
        self.weight_input.style.padding = 50
        box.add(self.weight_input)

        # Create the button to save the inputs
        save_button = toga.Button('Save', on_press=self.save_data)
        save_button.style.padding = 50
        box.add(save_button)

        self.main_window.content = box
        self.main_window.show()

    def save_data(self, widget):
        date = self.date_input.value
        weight = self.weight_input.value
        print(f"Date: {date}, Weight: {weight}")  # For debugging purposes
        with open('weight_data.csv', 'a') as f:
            f.write(f"{date},{weight}\n")

def main():
    return WeightApp('Weight Tracker', 'org.beeware.weighttracker')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main().main_loop()


Hi Ismail. Did you mean to post this to the main Stack Overflow site? It doesn't appear to have anything to do with WordPress.
